# help with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to replace html text that closed by tag

start_ticker
code....
 end_ticker

i don't success

my  code is

```
$string_html = preg_replace('/<!-- start_ticker -->.*<!-- end_ticker -->/i',"bla bla",$string_html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default "." doesn't match newlines - you can add the "s" (DOTALL) modifier to change this.
I suspect that's your problem.

```
$string_html = preg_replace('/<!-- start_ticker -->.*<!-- end_ticker -->/is',"bla bla",$string_html);
```

Comment: /in replace me every thing and i get empty string

Comment: I made a typo the first time - should have been /is

Comment: If you don't want to replace the comments then combine this with @soulmerge's answer

Comment: Hmm... I don't think there's any way it can give you an empty string - are you sure you haven't made a typo when you print it out?

Comment: another details in this 2 tags i have many lines of html like table, tr ,  td

Comment: is was my stupid mistake 
preg_replace('/<!--\s*start_ticker\s*-->.*?<!--\s*end_ticker\s*-->/is',"bla",$string_html);

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that problem even without using regular expressions:

```
$start = '<!-- start_ticker -->';
$end = '<!-- end_ticker -->';
$replacement = 'blabla';
$posStart = stripos($str, $start);
if ($posStart !== false) {
    $posEnd = stripos($str, $end, $posStart);
    if ($posEnd !== false) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, $posStart) . $replacement . substr($str, $posEnd + strlen($end));
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend this. It should be faster then the PCREs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to keep the start/end tags. Then you need to capture them with brackets:

```
$string_html = preg_replace('/(<!-- start_ticker -->).*(<!-- end_ticker -->)/i', '$1bla bla$2', $string_html);
```

Beware though, that regular expressions are not the best choice when it comes to html.

Comment: That's not possible. It should at least contain blabla

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$match1 = '<!-- start_ticker -->';
$match2 = '<!-- end_ticker -->';
$replace = 'bla bla';
$string = preg_replace("/$match1(.*?)$match2/is", $match1.$replace.$match2, $string);
```

Note that (.*?) makes a large difference since it makes the match ungreedy. This is when the pattern will be matched to the largest number of possible permutations of that pattern, rather then the least.

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Greedy

Otherwise, you would match from the first  to the last  clobbering anything in between if there are multiple matches.